# How to update User information in database in case of form authentication ticket is Expire?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm using form authentication for user login and logout. I have a problem when the user authentication ticket is expire in this time i want to update some information in database . but in this time user information in the ticket is null

Answer (score 0):

I increased the Forms authentication ticket expiration time to twice the Session expiration time to avoid the ticket expiration before the session times out.

Please read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443) for more information